# Delete object with primary key as CharField with DestroyAPIView Django REST framework

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, http-delete

I have a tracking model with Charfield as primary key:

```
    tracking_code = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
```

I built a destroy API with django REST framework as below:

```
class ShipmentPackAPIView(viewsets.GenericViewSet, generics.DestroyAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, )
    serializer_class = ShipmentPackUpdateSerializer
    queryset = ShipmentPack.objects.all()
```

When i delete one tracking code has value = "1.886729767250155854" by http DELETE method:

`curl -X "DELETE" http://localhost:8000/tracking_code/1.886729767250155854/`

It's not found!

But I query with django model it's found and I deleted other normally.

Thanks for the help and sorry for bad English!